# Why is the solution of a system of two nonlinear, simultaneous algebraic equations in two variables a constant?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

If 
$$\begin{gathered}
  {f_{11}}({x_1}) + {f_{12}}({x_2}) = {c_1}, \hfill \\
  {f_{21}}({x_1}) + {f_{22}}({x_2}) = {c_2}, \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are real constants, the $f_{ij}$'s are real functions of one real variable and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the unknowns,
why does that imply that both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are constant? Is it simply because there are two equations and two unknowns?

EDIT: The functions $f_{ij}$ are not constant functions.

Comment: They don't. Consider all the $f_{ij}$ constant functions then $x_1$ and $x_2$ can take any values while satisfying these equations.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the functions $f_{ij}$ are not constant functions (they are in fact given by ${f_{ij}}({x_i}) = {\int g _{ij}}({x_1},{x_2})d{x_j}$ where $g_{ij}$  are some other functions)

Comment: EDIT: that should be $dx_i$